# Instantiate an object and call method returning a value in C# or C++ with single line of syntax?

Tags: c#, c++

I refreshing myself on C# and C++ after having spent some time coding in other languages.  I was wondering if I could do something like this:

```
class Customer
{
    private long id;

    public Customer()
    {
        id = 0;
    }

    public Customer(long initID)
    {
        id = initID;
    }

    public bool Add()
    {
        // TODO: Call web service to add a customer to the database
        // ...
        return true;
    }

}
```

... the call

```
        // Add Customer
        // Two line way that is correct
        Customer c = new Customer(1234);
        bool isAdded = c.Add();
        // One line way that isn't valid
        bool isAdded = new Customer(1234).Add();
```

In other words, I don't really need the Customer object ... basically instantiate the object with a value and run the method and return the result of the method and dispose of the object ... all in a single statement.

Is there a way to do this as clean and as simple in one line in C# and/or C++?

Comment: So... use a static class?

Comment: You can do it in C# because it will garbage collect the object for you, but in (unmanaged) C++ you will leak said object.

Comment: What isn't valid about your attempt?  What error do you get?

Comment: Oh wow, David and Paul ... you are correct!  I just assumed it would not work and in fact it does work in C# ... but not in C++.  ... hmmm I can't seem to flag your answers as correct only as "useful"?  Sach's answer is also technically correct but not the desired implementation.

Comment: As C++ and C# are different and required different answers, it does not make much sense to combine both questions into one. Also, given that it already works in both languages (in C++, you could create an unnamed temporary object), with very minor changes, it seems to show not much efforts were made in trying it first.

Comment: Phil1970, Actually I did try this first but had forgotten to change the variable name in my quick test sample so was getting an immediate error which made me think the construct was wrong ... perhaps you shouldn't jump to conclusion on "my efforts" and any particular reason for your jabs or are you just having a bad day?

Answer (score 1):

Create a static class (you'd want to name it better though)

```
public static class CustomerOperations
{
    public static bool Add(long initId)
    {
        // Do stuff using initId
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then call it so:

```
var isAdded = CustomerOperations.Add(1234);
```

Comment: I can use a Static class, but that would mean I can't use it when I do actually need to instantiate ... also Static means I can't inherit ... so I would end up duplicating code.